# how to float element without considering elements height

Tags: html, css

I have a menu including some ul and li.

how can I float ul's to left or right but not depend on previous element height.

screen shot:

[image]

for example men's shoes are not in a right place.

Comment: unclear about what you are asking. Can you put a [SSCE](http://www.sscce.org/) on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're looking for something more like http://masonry.desandro.com/ . Float actually won't get you the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wrap each row of floated elements in like a `<div>` or something. Like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```